# Can you repeatedly and recursively mirror site with wget without creating copies of the directory structure?

Tags: bash, wget

I want to store a site hosting a lot of pdf files by grabbing the pdfs with wget while preserving the directory structure of the site. I want to wget back to the site at regular intervals in order to copy any new files on the site -- but only re-download the new files and/or directories. In other words, I want to avoid copying content that has already been copied by a previous wget run.

The problem is almost solved by running the following:

```sh
wget -nv -m -np -c -w 3 --no-check-certificate -a /path/to/logfile -R "index.html*" -P /path/to/copy "https://source.site/source-directory/"
```

This only copies new files but seems to create new file instances of directories and sub-directories naming them directory.1, directory/sub-directory.1 etc. Is there a way to avoid this behaviour?

Comment: edit your Q to include output from small sample like `ls -ld directory/sub-dir*` . Maybe it is a permissions issue? Good luck.

Comment: Have you tried including `-N`?

Comment: According to the man-page, `-m` is equivalent to `-r -N -l inf --no-remove-listing`, so time-stamping should be enabled.

Comment: This likely happens when Wget can't distinguish between a directory and a file. If the page automatically returns the data for `/foo/index.html` when Wget requested `/foo`.